# How do I create another line without the previous deleting - Canvas - JavasScript - HTML5 - CSS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

let isPainting = false;
let lineWidth = 5;
let startX;
let startY;

toolbar.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.id === 'clear') {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});

toolbar.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(e.target.id === 'stroke') {
        ctx.strokeStyle = e.target.value;
    }

    if(e.target.id === 'lineWidth') {
        lineWidth = e.target.value;
    }
    
});

const draw = (e) => {
    if(!isPainting) {
        return;
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvasOffsetX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isPainting = true;
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    isPainting = false;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    background: #7F7FD5;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #91EAE4, #86A8E7, #7F7FD5);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #91EAE4, #86A8E7, #7F7FD5);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#toolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #202020;
}

#toolbar * {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#toolbar label {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#toolbar input {
    width: 100%;
}

#toolbar button {
    background-color: #1565c0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:white;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Drawing app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div id="toolbar">
            <h1>Draw.</h1>
            <label for="stroke">Stroke</label>
            <input id="stroke" name='stroke' type="color">
            <label for="lineWidth">Line Width</label>
            <input id="lineWidth" name='lineWidth' type="number" value="5">
            <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
        <div class="drawing-board">
            <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am making a simple line drawer and this is what I have so far. One of the main features i need it to have is solid straight lines as this is for a bigger project in which this is meant to represent pipes. So the lines cannot bend or curve but must be how the code shows it to be. The issue i am having now is if i want to have the lines to stay on the canvas after another mouse down and click then the lines aren't straight and is almost a paint application. I have provided the code down below.

```js
const canvasEle = document.getElementById('drawContainer');
const context = canvasEle.getContext('2d');
let startPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
let lineCoordinates = {x: 0, y: 0};
let isDrawStart = false;

const getClientOffset = (event) => {
    const {pageX, pageY} = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
    const x = pageX - canvasEle.offsetLeft;
    const y = pageY - canvasEle.offsetTop;

    return {
       x,
       y
    } 
}

const drawLine = () => {
    if(!isDrawStart) {
        return;
    }
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
   context.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
   context.stroke();
}

const mouseDownListener = (event) => {
   startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
   isDrawStart = true;
}

const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {
  if(!isDrawStart) return;
  
  lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
  clearCanvas();
  drawLine();
}

const mouseupListener = (event) => {
  isDrawStart = false;
}

const clearCanvas = () => {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEle.width, canvasEle.height);
}

canvasEle.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener);
canvasEle.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener);
canvasEle.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupListener);

canvasEle.addEventListener('touchstart', mouseDownListener);
canvasEle.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseMoveListener);
canvasEle.addEventListener('touchend', mouseupListener);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    background: #7F7FD5;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #91EAE4, #86A8E7, #7F7FD5);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #91EAE4, #86A8E7, #7F7FD5);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#toolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #202020;
}

#toolbar * {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#toolbar label {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#toolbar input {
    width: 100%;
}

#toolbar button {
    background-color: #1565c0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:white;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>


    <body>

        <canvas id = "drawContainer" width = "500" height = "500" style = "border: 1px solid #333;"></canvas>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what i thought but then that results in lines being continuously drawn as i'm moving the mouse around on the axis

Comment: Ouch ... Then you've to add `mousemove` and `mouseup` events in `mousedown` handler, and remove those events in `mouseup` handler, or alternatively keep a flag of the state.

Comment: What would that look like within the the Mousedown handler?

Comment: It looks like you'd like to see the line when you're drawing it. I'd suggest you to use a transparent overlaying canvas. While drawing, draw the line to the overlaying canvas (and calling also clearCanvas), and when finished (mouseup), draw the line to the underlaying canvas and clear the overlaying canvas.

Comment: @Teemu I'll give it a try, i just posted another program with similar rule sets which is essentially a paint program - wondering if there is a way i could almost make them have a baby

Comment: It's possible to draw the lines to a single canvas, but that requires you to "record" the old lines, and redraw them every time a new line will be drawn. It's much easier with two canvases, [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/tmpurs96/).

Comment: @Teemu This is great and is exactly what i need but for some reason when i paste this all to VSC it doesn't run or draw or show the canvas as it does in the browser of jsfiddle?

Comment: That's an entirely new problem, maybe you should ask a new question about it.

Comment: @Teemu Okay thank you've been a great help!

Comment: @Teemu I did what you said, if you'd like to see how the discussion is going - feel free to join in.

Comment: I just read it for a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: @Teemu I think I'm just going to continue learning and stop with the projects because it's becoming apparent that I don't know nearly enough than I feel I should

Comment: This goes a bit off-topic, but ... A small project is a good "tool" for learning. Then you really have to study the features and read documentations, and apply the information to the project. You'll remember things much better, it's more like "deep learning", and is much more effective than apply the skills to simple but meaningless examples.

Comment: @Teemu Okay I get you. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

### Adding line segments

I am guessing this is what you are after. A set of line segments added as the use clicks and drags (mouse or touch)

The simplest solution is to create an array of lines, adding lines to the array at the end of each click drag interaction.

### Example

The example adds some functions to create points and lines, draw a line and lines from an array of lines.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), lines = [];
const Point = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x,y});
const Line = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});
var currentLine = Line(Point(), Point()), addingLine = false;
["mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseup", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"].forEach(name => canvas.addEventListener(name, mouseEvent));
function getClientOffset(event, point) {
    event = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
    point.x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    point.y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
function drawLine(line) {
   ctx.moveTo(line.p1.x, line.p1.y);
   ctx.lineTo(line.p2.x, line.p2.y);
}
function UpdateDisplay() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (const l of lines) { drawLine(l) }
    addingLine && drawLine(currentLine); 
    ctx.stroke();
}
function mouseEvent(event) {
    if (event.type === "mousedown" || event.type === "touchstart") {
        getClientOffset(event, currentLine.p1);
        getClientOffset(event, currentLine.p2);
        addingLine = true;
        UpdateDisplay();
    } else if (event.type === "mouseup" || event.type === "touchend") {
        lines.push(currentLine);
        currentLine = Line(Point(), Point());
        addingLine = false;
        UpdateDisplay();
    } else if(addingLine) {
        getClientOffset(event, currentLine.p2);
        UpdateDisplay();
    }
}
```

```html
        <canvas id = "canvas" width = "500" height = "500" style = "border: 1px solid #333;"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works nicely with lines, but I doubt OP has more drawingtools, the app draws circles and propbably other shapes too, you'd need to record all the shapes.